# phpmyadmin displays text in place of login page

Tags: phpmyadmin

`localhost/phpmyadmin` shows text in place of  the login page. I use apache2 web server for accessing `PHPMyAdmin`.

The web page shows code as below and there are many more: -

```
addJSON( 'list', PMA_RecentFavoriteTable::getInstance('recent')->getHtmlList() ); exit; } if ($GLOBALS['PMA_Config']->isGitRevision()) { if (isset($_REQUEST['git_revision']) && $GLOBALS['is_ajax_request'] == true) { PMA_printGitRevision(); exit; } echo '
'; } // Handles some variables that may have been sent by the calling script $GLOBALS['db'] = ''; $GLOBALS['table'] = ''; $show_query = '1'; // Any message to display? if (! empty($message)) { echo PMA_Util::getMessage($message); unset($message); } $common_url_query = PMA_URL_getCommon(); $mysql_cur_user_and_host = ''; // when $server > 0, a server has been chosen so we can display // all MySQL-related information if ($server > 0) { include 'libraries/server_common.inc.php'; include 'libraries/StorageEngine.class.php'; // Use the verbose name of the server instead of the hostname // if a value is set $server_info = ''; if (! empty($cfg['Server']['verbose'])) { $server_info .= htmlspecialchars($cfg['Server']['verbose']); if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo']) { $server_info .= ' ('; } } if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo'] || empty($cfg['Server']['verbose'])) { $server_info .= $GLOBALS['dbi']->getHostInfo(); } if (! empty($cfg['Server']['verbose']) && $GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo']) { $server_info .= ')'; } $mysql_cur_user_and_host = $GLOBALS['dbi']->fetchValue('SELECT USER();'); // should we add the port info here? $short_server_info = (!empty($GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['verbose']) ? $GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['verbose'] : $GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['host']); } echo '
' . "\n"; // Anchor for favorite tables synchronization. echo PMA_RecentFavoriteTable::getInstance('favorite')->getHtmlSyncFavoriteTables(); echo '
'; if ($server > 0 || count($cfg['Servers']) > 1 ) { if ($cfg['DBG']['demo']) { echo '
'; echo '
```

**Update**
I was able to solve this problem by trying this on the browser:-
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/?

Comment: Looks like coding problem. Maybe some illegal chars were parsed as ?> which terminates code block.

Comment: I have not changed anything on it. It was working till yesterday but suddenly today it stopped.

Comment: Apache seems not interpreting PHP instructions. This may be because your PHP module is not enable or activated in apache.
Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478365/cant-load-phpmyadmin-index-site

Answer (score 19):

You have to install apache2 php package.

```
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php
```

Answer (score 6):

The same thing happened to me after installing PHP 7.3, 7.2 and 5.6 and then purging PHP 5.6 and PHP 7.3..

I did the following steps:

1. `a2enmod php7.3`
2. `systemctl restart apache2`

Then everything worked well.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem, try this:

`sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Add at or near the `<Directory>` tags:

`<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        php_flag engine on
        Require all granted
</Directory>`

Answer (score 0):

It is probably caused by a faulty change in the config file that terminated a string (with ') or a code block (with ?>). If you didn't do that manually then your site might be hacked. Check your config files and try reinstalling phpMyAdmin and set config files to read-only.

EDIT: Could you please include the version of your phpMyAdmin and/or a link to the installation package of it.